# How to reach to specific layers in a SpatRaster from a layer with indices?

Tags: r, raster, terra

I have a raster brick with multiple values, and I need to reach to specific layers within it. The positions are given by a single "index raster layer".

Hope this is clear enough, I have thought of using extract or values somehow, but am not sure how to implement that here.

```
library(terra)
a <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
values(a) <- c(1,2,3,4)
names(a) <- "layer_one"

b <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
values(b) <- c(5,6,7,8)
names(b) <- "layer_two"

c <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
values(c) <- c(9,10,11,12)
names(c) <- "layer_three"

brick <- c(a,b,c)

layer_indices <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
values(layer_indices) <- c(1,3,2,3)
names(layer_indices) <- "layer_indices"

# desired output
output <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
values(output) <- c(1,10,7,12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
out <- selectRange(brick, layer_indices)
```

Comment: Perfect - I was about to try to split the layer_indices in a bunch of "masks" and it would be chaos. Thanks a lot!